# Covariance and correlation of a bi-variate random variable

Tags: probability

Referencing the part marked with the red arrow in the images below:

[image]

[image]

Also in example 2.4.8 its worked out that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$, and in example 2.4.12, $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2\pi}+\mu^2$, and $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[X] = \sigma^2$

---

What I do not understand is how did they get $\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[X,Y]=\rho$? I thought $\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[X,Y]=\mathbb{E}[XY] -\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$. But $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is not even worked out in the question?

Comment: Both $X$ and $Y$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot abt that!

Answer (score 0):

As you say, $\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y] = \mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$. They computed $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\rho$. Look at the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$. They computed the marginal pdf for $X$ and came up with
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
That's none other than the standard normal density, the pdf for $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, which has mean $0$. Certainly this makes sense, because the pdf $f(x)$ is even, i.e., symmetric about $x=0$. Any random variable with an even pdf must have mean $0$ (or have undefined mean, e.g., the Cauchy distribution).

The marginal distribution for $Y$ is exactly the same as the marginal distribution for $X$, so $\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$ as well. One can see that by examining the density function $f(x,y)$: note that it stays exactly the same if one interchanges $x$ and $y$. That is,
$$
f(x,y) = f(y,x).
$$
This symmetry implies $X$ and $Y$ have exactly the same marginal distributions and so exactly the same means.